# Laravel Digital Ocean Error in exception handler

Tags: php, laravel-4, digital-ocean

I have followed through the phpacademy digital ocean tutorial in order to try and get my laravel site set up. After following through the steps there was a difference between my setup and theirs. My default index.html page was located at `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www`

I removed the index.html page and uploaded my laravel app. I am not using any DB connections (just using static content). I developed my site locally with vagrant and homestead.

After uploading the app and going to the IP address I get the Laravel app directory listing. When I went into public I got a message saying mcrypt was require/not installed. I installed it with `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` and restarted the server.

Again I reloaded the page and I get the following message (after turning debugging to true) "Error in exception handler: The stream or file

> "/var/www/html/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:84"

How do I fix this and can i remove the /public and just use straight IP / domain (once i get that far)

Comment: Could you please point me a link to the tutorial you used? I run PHP and NGinX on my site on DO, so I doubt that DO is the problem. **I do not understand what web server you are using**.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-ok9d_6xrc Although my droplet is Ubuntu 14.10 x64 vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error message indicates it can't open your log file there. Assuming you're using this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-lts-vps), take a look at the subsection "Fixing Permissions", you'll need to chmod your storage directory.

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/app/storage
```

Comment: No I had not see that tutorial. I was using this series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-ok9d_6xrc

Comment: Alright, same advice should apply. I'd ensure you have the right permissions setup for that storage directory.

Comment: Thanks will give that a blast

Answer (score 0):

Start artisan with sudo. This will give artisan all the permissions it needs and won't make any security troubles as well.

so instead starting artisan serve with:

```
$ php artisan serve
```

try using:

```
$ sudo php artisan serve
```

thus you wont have to make any permission changes